# Argo workflow when a condition for substring match

Tags: kubernetes, conditional-statements, argo-workflows, argocd

I want to execute a task in Argo workflow if a string starts with a particular substring.
For example, my string is `tests/dev-or.yaml` and I want to execute task if my string starts with `tasks/`

Here is my workflow but the condition is not being validated properly

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: conditional-
spec:
  entrypoint: conditional-example
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: should-print
      value: "tests/dev-or.yaml"

  templates:
  - name: conditional-example
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: should-print
    steps:
    - - name: print-hello
        template: whalesay
        when: "{{inputs.parameters.should-print }} startsWith 'tests/'"

  - name: whalesay
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay:latest
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["cowsay hello"]
```

Below is the error it is giving when I run the workflow

```
WorkflowFailed 7s workflow-controller  Invalid 'when' expression 'tests/dev-or.yaml startsWith 'tests/'': Unable to access unexported field 'yaml' in token 'or.yaml'
```

Seems it is not accepting `-`, `.yaml` and `/` while evaluating the when condition.

Any mistake am making in my workflow? What's the right way to use this condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr - use this: `when: "'{{inputs.parameters.should-print}}' =~ '^tests/'"`

Parameter substitution happens before the `when` expression is evaluated. So the when expression is actually `tests/dev-or.yaml startsWith 'tests/'`. As you can see, the first string needs quotation marks.

But even if you had `when: "'{{inputs.parameters.should-print}}' startsWith 'tests/'"` (single quotes added), the expression would fail with this error: `Cannot transition token types from STRING [tests/dev-or.yaml] to VARIABLE [startsWith]`.

Argo Workflows [conditionals](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/tree/master/examples#conditionals) are evaluated as [govaluate](https://github.com/Knetic/govaluate) expressions. govaluate [does not have any built-in functions](https://github.com/Knetic/govaluate/blob/master/MANUAL.md#built-in-functions), and Argo Workflows does not augment it with any functions. So `startsWith` is not defined.

Instead, you should use govaluate's [regex comparator](https://github.com/Knetic/govaluate/blob/master/MANUAL.md#regex-comparators--). The expression will look like this: `when: "'{{inputs.parameters.should-print}}' =~ '^tests/'"`.

This is the functional Workflow:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: conditional-
spec:
  entrypoint: conditional-example
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: should-print
        value: "tests/dev-or.yaml"
  templates:
    - name: conditional-example
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: should-print
      steps:
        - - name: print-hello
            template: whalesay
            when: "'{{inputs.parameters.should-print}}' =~ '^tests/'"
    - name: whalesay
      container:
        image: docker/whalesay:latest
        command: [sh, -c]
        args: ["cowsay hello"]
```

Comment: The condition is not working in my workflow, It is giving this error `'Invalid ''when'' expression ''tests/dev-or.yaml =~ ''tests/dev-or.yaml'''': Unable to access unexported field ''yaml'' in token ''or.yaml'''`

Comment: Can you paste the exact expression you’re using?

Comment: here is the expression am using `when: "'{{item}}' =~ '^tests/'"`
Running this in a loop with `withParam`

Comment: That looks fine to me… but it doesn’t look at all like it matches the error message. Do you have the raw string representation of {{item}} for the failing iteration of the loop? Maybe something in the variable us screwing up the expression.

Comment: Let me share the string am getting in loop

Comment: Apologies, seems the condition is working flawlessly, but my workflow is wrong. I accepted your answer. You are adding a lot of value in stackoverflow for argo questions. Appreciate your efforts

Comment: No worries, workflows are debase reading.  Good luck! I watch the argo-workflows tag, so might drop in if the other issue becomes a question.

Comment: I was trying to fix my workflow. Does argo workflow allows us to use when condition along with `artifacts`. because it is giving an error for me when I use artifiacts along with when condition. The error is `failed to resolve {{inputs.artifacts.Code}}`. the artifact am passing for the workflow is              

`artifacts:`
   `- name: Code`
      `from: "{{inputs.artifacts.Code}}"`

Comment: I think the answer is yes, but I’m not 100% sure what you’re asking. Wanna open another question and drop your workflow spec in it?

Comment: Yeah I'll post another question.

Comment: I opened another question